# How can I build a laser detector whit ILX554B CCD linear?

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics, ccd

I am trying to build a CCD camera with a Sony ILX554B CCD Linear sensor to work with optical experiments. My problem is that I have this sensor, but I can't find an explanation or relevant circuit to use it in.

How can I build this CCD camera and work with the data from this sensor?

**merge:**

this is what i want exactly to build whit my ILX554B CCD sensor but i don't have any idea about this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut9LfQmaYkU . So can you help me please ?

Comment: A link to the data sheet would help a lot.

Comment: http://www.npk-photonica.ru/images/ilx554b_1_.pdf there is the link to the datasheet @Andyaka

Comment: I'm no expert on these types of chip but the data sheet appears to have everything covered including a circuit and timing diagrams.

Comment: You need to provide more context to *YOUR* question without having people needing to go watch some random video somewhere else.  Please state clearly what it is that you are trying to do and show us what attempts you have already made - and why they aren't working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be nice to know at which level of knowledge you are, but here are several tips:

1. The camera involves optics as well. Thus, you will need to design an optical system to focus an object on the image sensor.
2. You need to create a CCD driver. The driver will provide command signals to the sensor and well as the clock - ROG and CLK, pp. 4-6. You might get away with using just a microcontroller (since this sensor does not seem to have a complicated interface), but it is more common to use some CPLDs, FPGAs, or other logic that is less noisy.
3. You should have a little research on how image sensors work and output signals (hint: shift register). This sensor, as the most of other CCD sensors, has analog output. On every signal clock of the readout cycle you need to sample the video output of the sensor - that will be the intensity at each pixel represented in a voltage value. Page 10 shows a typical sensor/hardware interface. It says that the maximum voltage range for the signal is 1V, and the dark offset is 2.85V. Thus, ideally, if the pixel is at dark, the voltage for that pixel will be 2.85V. As more light strikes a particular pixel, the voltage will be dropping below 2.85V for that pixel. When you provide enough illumination to saturate the pixel, the output will be 1.85V. Sampling of pixel values should occur at particular times, see the figure on p.7.
4. You can add an ADC converter to digitize your output. That will require more hardware to implement on the board. If that is a problem, you might consider to switch to a sensor with a digital output, many CMOS line sensors have digital output (ADCs built-in).
5. Linear sensor does not give you a 2D area image. If you need your camera to produce an area image, you will need to scan the object and then combine the lines into a 2D image. Or consider a 2D image sensor, if possible.

Comment: thank you i will try to check every point of what u'v said :)